# PHP: Counting binary values of '1's in positive integer

Tags: php, html

I want to count how many binary '1's are in an text input between 0 and 65535.

In the code: The variable $a contains a positive integer between 0 and 65535.

Here I provided a solution.
What would be the best solution?
Please give me your recommendations

**functions.php**

```
    <?php
    require_once './config.php';

    /**
     * provides the number of "1" digits in the binary conversion of a decimal
     * number
     * @param int $a
     * @return int
     */
    function get_ones_from_binary_presentation_of_decimal($a) {
      if(!is_numeric($a)) {
        return false;
      }
      if($a < 0 OR $a > MAX_INT) {
        return -1;
      }
      $binary = decbin($a);
      $one_count = strlen(preg_replace('/0/', '', $binary));  
      return $one_count;
    }

    function get_ones($ones) {
      return ($ones == 1) ? "one" : "ones";
    }

    $basic_int = ($post['fromInt']) ? $post['fromInt'] : DECIMAL_NUMBER;
    $ones = get_ones_from_binary_presentation_of_decimal($basic_int);
    if (!$ones) {
      print '&quot;' . $basic_int . '&quot; is not a number.';
    }
    else if ($ones == -1) {
      print 'Please choose a number between 0 and 65535!';
    }
    else {
      print $basic_int . ' contains binary ' . $ones . ' ' . get_ones($ones);
    }

/**
 * sanitzes arrays recoursively like GET or POST
 */
function sanitize($elem) {
  if (!is_array($elem)) {
    $elem = htmlentities($elem, ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8");
  } else {
    foreach ($elem as $key => $value) {
      $elem[$key] = sanitize($value);
    }
  }
  return $elem;
}
```

**index.php**

```
<?php
  require_once './config.php';

  $post = sanitize($_POST);

  if ($post['submitted'] == 1) {
    $int = $post['fromInt'];
  }
  else {
    $int = DECIMAL_NUMBER;
  }


?>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Binary ONEs</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/frontend.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <form method="post" action="<?php print $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>">
      <label for="fromInt">Integer (bis 65.535): </label>
      <input id="fromInt" name="fromInt" size="5" value="<?php print $int ?>" />
      <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Calculate" />
      <input type="hidden" name="submitted" value="1" />
    </form>
    <div id="out"><?php include 'functions.php'; ?></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

**config.php**

```
<?php

// Decimal to binary number
define('DECIMAL_NUMBER', 21);

// integert-limit
define('MAX_INT', 65535);
```

Comment: So, does this code work?  Not work?  MIght you want to post this at Code Review (https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) instead?

Answer (score 0):

**Your issue is:** *I want to count how many binary '1's are in an text input between 0 and 65535. (...) What would be the best solution? Please give me your recommendations*

**The answer for that issue is:**

```
echo substr_count(decbin(rand(0, 65535)), 1);
```

where `rand` function is replaced by your sanitized input.

Notice that I didn't take on your sanitizing routines, since I figure you're going to adapt it to your code.

If it isn't exactly what you wanted, please provide more details.

Comment: Thanks. That is great. More simple than strlen(preg_replace('/0/', '', $binary));
Do you think I need the sanitize?
Meanwhile I change it to a slider and a number input  field.

Comment: It is up to your system analysis. Do you think your code may receive invalid or even malicious inputs that could mess your algorithm? If there is the slightest chance of that, you should do it.